# LINQ selectors inheritance

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

It's not impossible that my question has already been answered here, but unfortunately when it comes to LINQ I can't always find the right search terms.
Given the underlying source code how do you think I can reuse Selectors.CustomerDTO selector within Selectors.CustomerExtendedDTO?
It should be possible since the input database entity is the same.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (NorthwindEntities ctx = new NorthwindEntities())
        {
            foreach (var item in ctx.Customers.Where(c => c.CompanyName.StartsWith("A")).Select(Selectors.CustomerDTO))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("CompanyName: {0}", item.CompanyName);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            foreach (var item in ctx.Customers.Where(c => c.CompanyName.StartsWith("A")).Select(Selectors.CustomerExtendedDTO))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("CompanyName: {0}", item.CompanyName);
                Console.WriteLine("ContactName: {0}", item.ContactName);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

class CustomerDTO
{
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}

class CustomerExtendedDTO : CustomerDTO
{
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

static class Selectors
{
    internal static Expression<Func<Customers, CustomerDTO>> CustomerDTO
    {
        get
        {
            return c => new CustomerDTO
            {
                CustomerID = c.CustomerID,
                CompanyName = c.CompanyName
            };
        }
    }

    internal static Expression<Func<Customers, CustomerExtendedDTO>> CustomerExtendedDTO
    {
        get
        {
            return c => new CustomerExtendedDTO
            {
                CustomerID = c.CustomerID,
                CompanyName = c.CompanyName,
                Address = c.Address,
                ContactName = c.ContactName
            };
        }
    }

}
```

Such thing would be very useful when the inherited projection entity does not only contain two properties but several dozens.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: The solution should be compilable to LINQtoEntities expressions.

Comment: I'm not sure if you should go this path. It causes tight coupling of your projection types. It would be the same effect as using AutoMapper and a tangle of inheriting target types. (Which, by the way, could be an alternative).